# Return type matched from multiple relationships in Neo4j with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I know that you can match on multiple relationships in Neo4j, like this example in the docs:

```
MATCH (wallstreet {title: 'Wall Street'})<-[:ACTED_IN|:DIRECTED]-(person)
RETURN person.name
```

which returns nodes with an ACTED_IN or DIRECTED relationship to 'Wall Street'.

However, is there a way to get the type of the relationship in this query? That is, I would like to return not only the name, but also *which relationship applies to him/her*, in order to see if it was the ACTED_IN, or the DIRECTED relationship that caused the result to be output.

You can do the equivalent here:

```
MATCH (:Person {name: 'Oliver Stone'})-[r]->(movie)
RETURN type(r)
```

but that's just matching on any relationship. I would like to do this, but only with the two relationships specified in the clause.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You no longer need additional colons in between valid edge types you are querying. otherwise you can use the variable just like you did in the unspecific edge case:

```
MATCH (:Movie{title: 'The Matrix'})<-[r:ACTED_IN|DIRECTED]-(person)
RETURN type(r), person.name
```

Comment: awesome thanks so much, this was exactly the syntax I was looking for!